# Change file ownership recursively without errors

Tags: find, chown

I am trying to write a script that fixes the ownership of all files owned by a specific user, after changing the user's UID.

Currently, I run:

```
chown -Rhc --from=${OLD_UID} ${NEW_UID} /
chown -Rhc --from=:${OLD_UID} :${NEW_UID} /
```

Where `OLD_UID` and `NEW_UID` are the old and new UIDs of the user I have just modified.

This has the desired effect, but always exits with a return code of 1, because of errors like this:

```
chown: cannot access ‘/proc/1103/task/1103/fd/4’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot access ‘/proc/1103/task/1103/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot access ‘/proc/1103/fd/4’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot access ‘/proc/1103/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
```

My theory is that the process finding all files picks up its own process, which then does not exist when `chown` tries to access it.

I could just throw away the return code from the commands, but I would prefer not to in case I end up ignoring real errors.

Can anyone suggest an alternative approach that will not report false errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `find`, and tell it to not descent into other filesystems (which should prevent it from accessing virtual filesystems like `proc`, `sys`, etc):

```
find / -xdev -uid ${OLD_UID} -execdir chown ${NEW_UID} {} +
```

This may not be as efficient.

Another way to filter out the virtual files would be to remount the root filesystem somewhere else:

```
mkdir /tmp/chroot
mount -o .. -t .. /dev/... /tmp/chroot
```

And run `chown` on `/tmp/chroot`.

Comment: In the case of the second solution, isn't there still `/tmp/chroot/dev`? Also, is it really safe to mount the same filesystem in two places?

Comment: @Barmar indeed, but none of the device files would be owned by a normal user, right? Some systems don't allow it, but some do. So, I don't know.

Comment: Of course, but the objective is to keep it from drilling into the device directory in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar *One of the objectives* is. If it really is important, bind-mounting an empty folder over `/tmp/chroot/dev` should solve that problem.

Comment: That seems to be the primary objective -- he just wants to prevent the errors when it tries to recurse into subdirectories that disappear while the command is running.

Comment: @Barmar And those directories are primarily in `/proc`, `/run`, etc., as are some files owned by normal users. Directories in `/dev` are not as transient, and I doubt any files there are owned by normal users (except `pts`, which is a virtual filesystem). `/dev` seems to be of secondary importance to me,  `/proc` and `/run` are primary.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me. I agree with your `find -xdev` solution to skip the virtual filesystems. My question was about the second solution of remounting the root filesystem, I don't see how it will prevent recursing into virtual filesystems.

Comment: @Barmar The virtual filesystems (proc, sys, devpts, etc.) and the tmpfs ones (usually `/run` or `/var/run`, etc.) are mounted on on the directory tree rooted at `/`, not on the filesystem underneath. The underlying filesystem does not contain any of the "files" provided by them (and is in general unaffected by them). Mounting it again at another point will give a view where only files residing on the filesystem (device files have inodes allocated) are shown. It's not so much that recursion into virtual filesystems is prevented, but that they aren't present in the first place (or second).

Comment: @Barmar That is why I have shown a full mount command and not a bind mount. A bind mount, on the other hand, will show everything that's seen in `/`, and nothing will be gained.

Comment: Never having tried this type of double mount, I assumed it was the other way around, my mistake.

Comment: @Barmar It's not often used, but it is one way of jaling something, while giving it full read-access but no write access: http://askubuntu.com/a/548712/158442 (in that case I'd used `/` directly, but could have mounted it on the chroot folder and unioned there, instead - it would have been more effort, but would give more control as well).